# Cowboy websocket handler: How to set timeout for first message?

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I have websocket connection between my server and client that should be kept alive until client close it. When opens connection client should authenticate himself by sending first message with token. If for some period of time after spawning websocket handler will not receive such message it should terminates. How to implement such timeout?

**NOTE**: idle_timeout option is not suitable as I need timeout only for first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start timer in your `websocket_init` callback on your own. 
If user authenticate before timeout, just ignore it, you can achieve this by updating the state when user authenticate himself.

`erlang:start_timer` documentation:

http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#start_timer-3